# How is it possible to include a php file in the header of a phpbb3 html file?

Tags: php, html, include, phpbb3

I am trying to include the header of my website in the header of the phpbb3 html file using

`<!-- INCLUDEPHP ../../../../header.inc -->`

I am using an inc file which doesn't work, it works when I use

`<!-- INCLUDE ../../../../header.inc -->`

but the php doesn't. I have also tried creating a php file called header.php which has the line

`<?php include("header.inc"); ?>`

but this does nothing! How can I get this to work!

Comment: AFAIK, you can not include PHP code in HTML file, its other way around, you can include HTML code in PHP

Comment: @Kumar you can if your server is set up to parse `html` for `php` code. `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html`: add this line or one very similar to a .htaccess file of an Apache server would allow you to insert `php` code into your html files.

Comment: Agree, but thats not what Yesterday is trying to do. Out of curiosity, why would you server html files through PHP?

Comment: I want to have a sidebar with the latest posts from mysql

Comment: The include function works but the includephp function doesn't

Comment: What I didn't realise is that you had to turn this feature on in the phpbb3 ACP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an absolute path

```
<?php include('/home/usr_name/www/includes/inc/header.inc') ?>
```

or a relative path

```
  <?php include('../../../../header.inc') ?>
```

Comment: no, the header.inc is in the same directory as the header.php file

Answer (score 4):

You need to login to the administration of your PHPBB3 board and Enable PHP Code In Templates

Once this is done, you are able to execute php in the html template files by using the following code:

```
<!-- PHP --> include("externalFile.php"); <!-- ENDPHP -->
```

Please see this blog post for more information about using PHP in PHPBB HTML templates.
http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/add-php-code-to-your-phpbb-forum-templates/

Comment: Just to note - enabling PHP in templates is an option on a main tab in server security settings. For __testing__ you might want to also disable template caching in load settings.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot include a php file in a html file (.html extension) unless you give the file a .php extension.

If your file is called header.php then you can use

```
<?php include("header.inc"); ?>
```

Just make sure the path is correct, maybe:

```
<?php include("../../../../header.inc"); ?>
```

Comment: Well it seems you can... http://area51.phpbb.com/docs/coding-guidelines.html#templating